# aspx.vb onChange de dropdownlist no funciona

Tags: vb.net, aspx

Hola buenos dias tengo un problema con una pagina que estoy reajustando, la pagina ya es algo vieja, esta hecha con vb.net.

El problema es que al momento de cambiar el item en un dropdownlist este no refleja el cambio.

**Codigo aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ModificaTitulo.aspx.vb" Inherits="Libros.ModificaTitulo"%>

<%@ Register Assembly="RJS.Web.WebControl.PopCalendar.Net.2008" Namespace="RJS.Web.WebControl"
    TagPrefix="rjs" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="App_Themes/TABContent/AjaxControlToolkit.Tabs.Tabs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="#f1f2d0">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    
             
 </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>   
<table align ="center" style="width: 304px; height: 54px;" ><tr>
                                <td align ="right" ><asp:Label runat="server" Text="Libro:" ID="Label1" 
                                        Font-Names="MS Reference Sans Serif" Font-Size="10pt"></asp:Label>
</td><td align ="left" ><asp:DropDownList ID="Existe2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Font-Names="MS Reference Sans Serif" Font-Size="9pt" Width="183px">
</asp:DropDownList>
                       </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>  
</td></tr></table>
```

**Codigo aspx.vb**

Aqui es donde esta el método escuchador del dropdownlist en el codebehind "ModificaTitulo.aspx.vb" pero no detecta el metodo ni me manda ningun error, ya hice de todo pero no logro encontrar el problema, intente añadiendo directamente el metodo al dropdownlist "OnSelectedChanged='Existe2_SelectedIndexChanged'" pero no funciono.

```
    Protected Sub Existe2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Existe2.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim myScript as String = "window.alert('Cambio el selector');"
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "myScript", myScript, True)
    End Sub
```

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar a resolver este problema y de antemano muchas gracias.